# Limiting time.sleep() function to one loop in python

Tags: python, loops, delay

I was creating a banking interface and I wanted yearly interest to be applied every 10 seconds (as part of a modified time scale).

```
import time

customers = 100
savings = []
fixdeposit = []

ask_user_type = """
What is your user type?
(type 1 if you're an employee)
(type 2 if you're a customer)
"""

employee_function_options = """
What function would you like to carry out?
(type 1 for total savings value)
(type 2 for a specific savings value)
(type 3 for total fixed deposit value)
(type 4 for a specific fd's value)
(type 5 to add a customer)
(type 6 to remove a customer)
(type 7 to end program)
"""

customer_function_options = """
What function would you like to carry out?
(type 1 for withdrawal)
(type 2 for deposit)
(type 3 for savings account balance)
(type 4 to create fixed deposit)
(type 5 to end fixed deposit)
(type 6 for fixed deposit value)
(type 7 to end program)
"""

for i in range (100):
    savings.append(1000)
    fixdeposit.append(0)

while 1 == 1:
    time.sleep(10)
    savings = [i * 1.04 for i in savings]
    fixdeposit = [i * 1.07 for i in fixdeposit]

user = int(input(ask_user_type))

while 1==1:
    if user == 1:
        function = int(input(employee_function_options))
        if function == 1:
            print (sum(savings))
            function = int(input(employee_function_options))

        elif function == 2:
            saving_account = int(input("What is the chosen account's number?"))
            print (savings[saving_account])
            function = int(input(employee_function_options))

        elif function == 3:
            print (sum(fixdeposit))
            function = int(input(employee_function_options))

        elif function == 4:
            fd_no = int(input("What is the chosen fd's number?"))
            print(fixdeposit[fd_no])
            function = int(input(employee_function_options))

        elif function == 5:
            no_new_customers = int(input("How many new customers do you want to add?"))
            for i in range(no_new_customers):
                savings.append(1000)
                fixdeposit.append(0)
            print ("Task Completed")
            function = int(input(employee_function_options))

        elif function == 6:
            account_deleted = int(input("What is the number of the account to be deleted?"))
            savings[account_deleted] = 0
            fixdeposit[account_deleted] = 0
            print ("Task Completed")
            function = int(input(employee_function_options))

        elif function == 7:
            print ("program ended")
            user = int(input(ask_user_type))

        else:
            print("Error")
            function = int(input(employee_function_options))


    elif user == 2:
        function = int(input(customer_function_options))
        if function == 1:
            account_no = int(input("What is your account number?"))
            withdrawal_amount = float(input("How much money do you want to withdraw?"))
            savings[account_no] = savings[account_no] - withdrawal_amount
            withdrawal_amount = 0
            function = int(input(customer_function_options))

        elif function == 2:
            account_no = int(input("What is your account number?"))
            deposit_amount = float(input("How much money do you want to deposit?"))
            savings[account_no] = savings[account_no] + deposit_amount
            deposit_amount = 0
            function = int(input(customer_function_options))

        elif function == 3:
            account_no = int(input("What is your account number?"))
            print(savings[account_no])
            function = int(input(customer_function_options))

        elif function == 4:
            account_no = int(input("What is your account number?"))
            fd_amount = float(input("How much money do you want in your fd?"))
            fixdeposit[account_no] = fd_amount
            fd_amount = 0
            function = int(input(customer_function_options))

        elif function == 5:
            account_no = int(input("What is your account number?"))
            savings[account_no] = savings[account_no] + fixdeposit[account_no]
            fixdeposit[account_no] = 0
            function = int(input(customer_function_options))

        elif function == 6:
            account_no = int(input("What is your account number?"))
            print(fixdeposit[account_no])
            function = int(input(customer_function_options))

        elif function == 7:
            user = int(input(ask_user_type))

        else:
            print("Error")
            function = int(input(customer_function_options))


    else:
        print("Error")
        user = int(input(ask_user_type))
```

I used `time.sleep()` but it seems to me that it prevents the user interface from working too.

Does anyone know any workarounds or ways to limit the `time.sleep()` function to the loop for interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `threading`, move the part that updates `savings` and `fixdeposit` to another thread. This is working example, I only truncated some parts of your code that didn't change, you will see `updating` printed every 10 seconds:

```
import threading
import time

customers = 100
savings = []
fixdeposit = []

ask_user_type = ...

employee_function_options = ...

customer_function_options = ...

for i in range (100):
    savings.append(1000)
    fixdeposit.append(0)


def regular_update():
    global savings, fixdeposit
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print('updating')
        savings = [i * 1.04 for i in savings]
        fixdeposit = [i * 1.07 for i in fixdeposit]


my_thread = threading.Thread(target=regular_update, args=())
my_thread.start()

user = int(input(ask_user_type))
... everything here as in your code
```

Comment: Instead of having the entire fixdeposit array update every time, is it possible for the interest to be applied on one particular element in the array (depending on the account_no of the user wanting to create the f.d.). Is there some different thread? I don't know how they work so I really need some help... Thanks.

Comment: To update one particular element you can just write `fixdeposit[account_no] = fixdeposit[account_no] * 1.07`. You can do it in `regular_update` thread or create another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop never breaks to allow other parts of your program to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
while 1 == 1:
    time.sleep(10)
    savings = [i * 1.04 for i in savings]
    fixdeposit = [i * 1.07 for i in fixdeposit]
```

Because of the condition `1 == 1` in your while-loop, it executes forever beause there is no way for the program to break from the loop internally. This means that your `time.sleep(10)` runs indefinitely.

---

**Update:**
Assuming you want a *valid* input from the user (depending on what you define as valid), you can do one of the following:

```py
number = (int)(input("Enter a number: "))

# 3 is just chosen here as a representative value
# The loop will run until 3 is received as input
while number != 3: 
  number = (int)(input("Enter a number: "))

print("Exited loop")
```

Or you can use the `break` statement to exit a loop when a condition is met:

```py
# 3 is just chosen here as a representative value
# The loop will run indefinitely, but if 3 is received as input, it will break the loop (force it to exit)
while 1 == 1:
  number = (int)(input("Enter a number: "))
  if number == 3:
    break

print("Exited loop")
```

Comment: How can I program it to break the loop upon receiving user input... Is that even possible?

Comment: @MananAgarwal Check my updated answer above. Don't forget to check the answer if it works for you.